# Aggregate, Mongoose - ignores duplicated results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema

```
var reviewSchema = new Schema({
    restaurantID: ObjectId,
    rating: {
     food: Number,
     service: Number,
     value: Number
    },
});
```

I want to get an array of average food, rating, service ratings so I do

```
 Review.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {
                            restaurantID: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(reviewData.restaurantid)
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $unwind: "$rating"
                    },
                    {
                        $group:{
                            _id: "$rating",
                            total_rating: { $avg: { $add: [ "$rating.food", "$rating.service", "$rating.value" ] } }
                        }
                    }
 ], function(review_error, reviews) {
```

However, first, it doesn't get the average of the three fields, it only gets the total of the fields. That's fine, I can divide it by 3 myself. The big problem is it ignores duplicated results. I tried to print the results out:

```
 [ { _id: { food: 4, service: 5, value: 4 }, total_rating: 13 },
  { _id: { food: 5, service: 5, value: 5 }, total_rating: 15 } ]
```

and I'm having 6 records of `{ _id: { food: 5, service: 5, value: 5 }, total_rating: 15 }` in the collection. How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

**Updated: Sample**

Review Collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d804d0d09e18b098208f"), 
    "rating" : {
        "food" : NumberInt(5), 
        "service" : NumberInt(5), 
        "value" : NumberInt(5)
    }, 
    "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"), 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d817d0d09e18b0982090"), 
    "rating" : {
        "food" : NumberInt(5), 
        "service" : NumberInt(5), 
        "value" : NumberInt(5)
    }, 
    "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"), 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d89161cc0a0e60f0925d"), 
    "rating" : {
        "food" : NumberInt(4), 
        "service" : NumberInt(5), 
        "value" : NumberInt(4)
    }, 
    "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"), 
}
```

Expected result

```
[ { _id: { food: 5, service: 5, value: 5 }, total_rating: 15 },
  { _id: { food: 4, service: 5, value: 4 }, total_rating: 13 },
  { _id: { food: 5, service: 5, value: 5 }, total_rating: 15 } ]
```

Actual result

```
   [ { _id: { food: 4, service: 5, value: 4 }, total_rating: 13 },
     { _id: { food: 5, service: 5, value: 5 }, total_rating: 15 } ]
```

Comment: Show a small sample of documents and an expected result that can actually be obtained "from that sample". That will make it clearer as to what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the post with a small sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). You're just trying to "average" the values in the document:

```
Review.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "average_rating": { "$avg": ["$rating.food", "$rating.service", "$rating.value" ]}
  }}
])
```

Returns:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d804d0d09e18b098208f"),
        "rating" : {
                "food" : 5,
                "service" : 5,
                "value" : 5
        },
        "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"),
        "average_rating" : 5
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d817d0d09e18b0982090"),
        "rating" : {
                "food" : 5,
                "service" : 5,
                "value" : 5
        },
        "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"),
        "average_rating" : 5
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d89161cc0a0e60f0925d"),
        "rating" : {
                "food" : 4,
                "service" : 5,
                "value" : 4
        },
        "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"),
        "average_rating" : 4.333333333333333
}
```

All you really want is the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) result over the three values and you can simply do that using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

The [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage is for "grouping", hence why the "same values" are being "grouped" together.

Also if you actually want "total" then the same applies to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
Review.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "average_rating": { "$avg": ["$rating.food", "$rating.service", "$rating.value" ]},
     "total_rating": { "$sum": ["$rating.food", "$rating.service", "$rating.value" ]}
  }}
])
```

And similar results for "each document":

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d804d0d09e18b098208f"),
        "rating" : {
                "food" : 5,
                "service" : 5,
                "value" : 5
        },
        "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"),
        "average_rating" : 5,
        "total_rating" : 15
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d817d0d09e18b0982090"),
        "rating" : {
                "food" : 5,
                "service" : 5,
                "value" : 5
        },
        "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"),
        "average_rating" : 5,
        "total_rating" : 15
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5af3d89161cc0a0e60f0925d"),
        "rating" : {
                "food" : 4,
                "service" : 5,
                "value" : 4
        },
        "restaurantID" : ObjectId("5ac962bd437c1e30e89406a8"),
        "average_rating" : 4.333333333333333,
        "total_rating" : 13
}
```

Comment: Works as I expected. Thanks for the quick answer and further information!